# Line broken text next to img, centered vertically

Tags: html, css

```
<img style="float: left;" width=200 height=200 src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQOrSSvhefLVAXo3OOoMGYGS232bfHFnZyA9Jk24KeefYuau8c">
    <div id="t">text next to it which will be line broken!</div>

#t
{
    float: left;
    line-height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4wMF/

well... as you can see, shrinking the width will cause the text goes underline. I want to achieve something like this:

[image: fax?]

Comment: why are you giving line height?

Comment: @Echo i'm guessing to vertically align his text in the div

Comment: if I wont give line-height, its not centered then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to align the text vertically in the centre of the div it would be a good idea to use the table-cell method here instead of line-height.

```
<div id="t"><p>text next to it which will be line broken!<p></div>
```

Try something like this

```
#t
{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    display: table;
}

#t p {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Comment: almost OK. But what if P has to be H1 ?

Comment: Use the h1 tag instead of p and replace #t p with #t h1 in the css

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of line-height. This will cause it wrap around as you described.

Try

```
img { display: block; }
#t { vertical-align: middle; }
```

There are other options for `vertical-align` so work with the one that works best for you.

Comment: it wont result in arranging the div middle